# How to get data by SqlDataReader.GetValue by column name

Tags: c#, sql

I use SqlDataReader.GetValue method to read values from DB:

```
Log.WriteLine("Value of CompanyName column:" + thisReader.GetValue(1));
```

As parameter GetValue get index of column.
How could I specify Column Name instead index?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
Log.WriteLine("Value of CompanyName column:" + thisReader["CompanyName"]);
```

Comment: I used as workaround following - 
`Log.WriteLine("Value of CompanyName column:" + thisReader.GetValue(thisReader.GetOrdinal("CompanyName")));`

What [] means?

Comment: @algot it's an indexed property, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

Comment: I don't understand the syntax "thisReader["CompanyName"]). It is in no way logical. Logical would be "thisReader.fields("CompanyName").value". But who am I to judge...

Comment: @tmighty: This is a very common notation for indexed collections, not only in C#. The index will often be an integer, but it can also be of another type, such as string.

Comment: Note to self, internally this does `return GetValue(GetOrdinal(name));` reference https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlDataReader.cs

Comment: @algot Thanks, that approach is useful when using the casting methods such as `GetInt32`.

Answer (score 55):

You can also do this.

```
//find the index of the CompanyName column
int columnIndex = thisReader.GetOrdinal("CompanyName"); 
//Get the value of the column. Will throw if the value is null.
string companyName = thisReader.GetString(columnIndex);
```

Comment: I was thinking in which case this could have more benefit then directly reading data from reader as thisReader["CompanyName"]. Can you please give any specific case for it? 
Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: @curiousBoy doing it this way will make it easier to check if the column exists, also makes sure the value you are selecting is in the correct dataformat e.g GetString, GetInt32 it doesnt just return an object you then have to cast. This is why i would use this method

Comment: @DavidMolyneux thx for your comment, as far as I understand from your explanation, it basically do "null check" for the string and throws an error in case of the value is null. This also makes me thing that this is just for the type of string. Other than that, for instance : "int productQuantiy = thisReader["ProductQuantity"] " would throw an error if the ProductQuantity doesn't have a valid int value, wouldn't it? thx again.

Comment: @curiousBoy  'int productQuantiy = thisReader["ProductQuantity"]' wouldnt work the compiler wont let you assign an object to a int you would have to parse/convert the object first.

Comment: @DavidMolyneux Please assume that I have used it as "int productQuantiy = Convert.ToInt32(thisReader["ProductQuantity"] )" .So that would throw an error if the ProductQuantity doesn't have a valid  convertible value , wouldn't it? I'm just trying to see how I could get more benefit by using that instead of directly reading the value from the reader? (for the string, as you have mentioned it throws an error, but what about for int?) Thx

Comment: For performance reasons, Microsoft now recommends you call your GetOrdinal outside your read loop, and only call GetString(int) inside the loop

Answer (score -4):

thisReader.GetString(int columnIndex)

Comment: Please add some explanation of how this answer actually *solves* the problem.