# Getting error in visual studio while reading from mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

In the following code I try to fill the combobox

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
  string sName = myReader.GetString("profesor"); <--- here is the error
  cb_1najprof.Items.Add(sName);
  cb_2najprof.Items.Add(sName);
  cb_3najprof.Items.Add(sName);
  cb_1najsprof.Items.Add(sName);
  cb_2najsprof.Items.Add(sName);
  cb_3najsprof.Items.Add(sName);
}
```

When the code above is run I get the error `cannot convert string to int` on the indicated line.

Comment: GetString expects an integer (index of the column in the select statement), not a field name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this..

```
string sName = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("profesor"));
```

or

```
string sName = myReader["profesor"].ToString();
```

Also see related question

[How to get data by SqlDataReader.GetValue by column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655965/how-to-get-data-by-sqldatareader-getvalue-by-column-name)

Answer (score 0):

`GetString` takes an integer as an argument, not a string. You have called it with `"profesor"`. Try calling it with eg `1` instead. This integer corresponds to the column you want to read from.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't pass a string to the .GetString() method [[documentation]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) You have to pass an int. The int (zero-based) is the column number you want to read.

*Yes I know my documentation link is for a SqlDataReader, but the same concept applies for a MySqlDataReader*