# Getting an IndexOutOfRangeException when putting sql into an object array

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

Currently working on a small tool for the company I am working at which shall handle the database. I have several classes handling various SQL functions, but whenever I try to put specific data from the database into a datagridview I get the Exception.

SQL function:

```
public class OUsersDB
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection Information");

    public SqlDataReader Select()
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT au.ApplicationId, au.UserId, au.UserName, au.MobileAlias, au.LastActivityDate, au.Name, sms.number, am.email FROM aspnet_users AS au " +
            " JOIN aspnet_membership AS am ON au.userid=am.userid " +
            " JOIN smsphonebooks AS sms ON au.name=sms.name";
        SqlDataReader ur = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return ur;

    }
}
```

Winform datagrid function

```
        public void Usersdb()
    {
        OUsersDB oudb = new OUsersDB();
        SqlDataReader ur = oudb.Select();
        myDataUsers.Rows.Clear();
        while (ur.Read())
        {
            object[] objUsers = {
                ur["au_ApplicationId"].ToString(),
                ur["au_UserId"].ToString(),
                ur["au_UserName"].ToString(),
                ur["au_MobileAlias"].ToString(),
                ur["au_LastActivityDate"].ToString(),
                ur["au_Name"].ToString(),
                ur["au_Phone"].ToString(),
                ur["au_Email"].ToString(), };
            myDataUsers.Rows.Add(objUsers);
            conn.Close();
        }
```

I have a similar sql function and object array futher up in the code which loads just fine, but once reaching this part I get the Exception on the

```
ur["au_ApplicationId"].ToString(),
```

It simply says

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'au_ApplicationId'

Comment: Selecting `au.ApplicationId` field and trying to get `au_ApplicationId` from reader.

Comment: Shouldn't the column be named "ApplicationId" only? Try removing the "au_". Same for the other columns.

Comment: Why not just use `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)`?  Not sure why you're filling the `DataTable myDataUsers` manually here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the obj to read the columns without the alias. You use aliases only to reference the columns in the query, but the output of the query won't have the aliases.

```cs
while (ur.Read())
        {
            object[] objUsers = {
                ur["ApplicationId"].ToString(),
                ur["UserId"].ToString(),
                ur["UserName"].ToString(),
                ur["MobileAlias"].ToString(),
                ur["LastActivityDate"].ToString(),
                ur["Name"].ToString(),
                ur["Phone"].ToString(),
                ur["Email"].ToString(), };
            myDataUsers.Rows.Add(objUsers);
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I did try without the alias beforehand, but still got the same response.

Comment: Did you check if this query is returning any rows? use `if (reader.HasRows)
        {` before the `while`

Comment: This is actually wrong, it's the alias you should use to look up the data not the original column name.

Comment: @RobinSalih you are wrong. I am talking about the TABLE alias, not the COLUMN alias. *au* is the TABLE alias, which is omitted in the end result, while the OP didn't place any COLUMN alias on his query, but rather he's using the original COLUMN names. Read the code better.

Comment: @Stormhashe Sorry, yes you are correct, I thought the columns were being aliased.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get ANY object, maybe you get nothing at all.

Comment: If they have no data returned then it will not enter the while loop where from within the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `IndexOutOfRangeException`, that's due to trying to access a column that doesn't exist in the reader.  Not sure why you're prefixing columns with "au_" when the `SELECT` statement is not doing this.

I would use [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead and add add this method to `OUsersDB`.

```
public void FillTable(DataTable table)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT au.ApplicationId, au.UserId, au.UserName, au.MobileAlias, au.LastActivityDate, au.Name, sms.number, am.email FROM aspnet_users AS au " +
        " JOIN aspnet_membership AS am ON au.userid=am.userid " +
        " JOIN smsphonebooks AS sms ON au.name=sms.name";
    using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        adapter.Fill(table)
}
```

Change calling code to:

```
public void Usersdb()
{
    OUsersDB oudb = new OUsersDB();
    myDataUsers.Rows.Clear();
    oudb.FillTable(myDataUsers);
}
```

Or here's a simple fix, instead.  Change your `SELECT` statement to alias column names as the code is expecting.

```
SELECT au.ApplicationId as au_ApplicationId, au.UserId as au_UserId, au.UserName as au_UserName, 
au.MobileAlias as au_MobileAlias, au.LastActivityDate as au_LastActivity, au.Name as au_Name, 
sms.number as au_Phone, am.email as au_Email -- REST OF QUERY UNCHANGED
```

Comment: Doesn't address the issue though.  By the way, a DataAdapter will open and close a connection for you, so you don't have to open it explicitly.

Comment: @LarsTech You're saying `SqlDataAdapter` (or base classes) have a finalizer for managed objects?  Because the code above doesn't call `Dispose`.  Not sure why this doesn't address the issue.  There's a `DataTable` they are trying to fill with a simple `SELECT`.  This fits the bill.

Comment: It doesn't address the index of range issue.  I didn't claim the DataAdapter disposes anything.  You don't need `conn.Open();` in your code above.  The DataAdapter will check to see if the connection is open, and if it isn't, it will open it.

Comment: @LarsTech I was referring to your claim that it closes the connection without being disposed of.  I'll remove the open.  I updated the answer to address the exception as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8656011/8512753

or remove the table aliases

```
ur["au_ApplicationId"].ToString(),
```

becomes

```
ur["ApplicationId"].ToString(),
```

and try assigning concrete values to the columns returned in your SQL

```
SELECT ApplicationId = au.ApplicationId, ...
```